# You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow

Tags: support, questions

How recent is "recent" in the following message?

> You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow.  Please contact a moderator if you require assistance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91097/getting-too-many-edits-further-edits-are-not-allowed-until-tomorrow/91107#91107) by @Marc Gravell♦, it appears that "(today/yesterday)" is considered recent. That question also includes information about why the rate limit is in place.

Based on how the term *today* is used elsewhere on the site, I'd assume that it means *posts created on the current UTC day and the UTC day previous to that*.

Comment: Why are we allowed just 5 edits every 2 days? I'd thought that SO is *supposed to be*  edit-heavy (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)?

Comment: That's incorrect @Pacerier. You are restricted to 5 edits _per day_  on _your own_ posts that are _more than_ two days old. Check out the answer I linked to for some of the reasons why that restriction exists.

Comment: Ic, but the whole point of editing is to up the quality of the post. And which posts better to start with other than the ones that one makes himself?