# Ability to edit my own posts (to remove my signatures)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, moderation

There is a restriction currently which allows only 5 edits per users irrespective of whether you own the post or not.

When I started using Stack Overflow, I used to sign all my posts (nearly 700, now). Today, I was trying to remove some of the signatures, but I wasn't allowed to proceed further 5 edits.

I know these restrictions are really important, but I feel this should be relaxed for the users with more reps say 10K (at least to edit their own posts).

@casperOne asked me to raise this as a meta topic when we discussed this in this post. Please refer the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857915/ruby-unique-elements-in-array/5858236#5858236) for more information.

Comment: "There is a restriction currently which allows only 5 edits per users irrespective of whether you own the post or not." I'm sure this restriction only applies to your own posts.

Comment: @Bolt is correct; this is an anti-ragequit measure. And those don't only happen with low-rep users either.

Comment: It looks like there are [116 posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A97572+Ramesh+Vel) currently signed in this way; I'm not sure if administrators can step in and perform some kind of bulk edit?

Comment: @meagar, it would be great.. i used to delete when i came across my own posts.. i am glad if someone would bulk remove them

Comment: Related: [Getting “Too many edits … Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91097)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed a handful of them for you.

But each time an edit occurs, it bumps the question to the front page.  Because we don't want the front page of Stack Overflow flooded with edited questions, I suggest you simply spend a few minutes each day doing the five you are allowed.

Also, we would be grateful if you could fix the spelling, grammatical and capitalization errors also.  I found quite a few in the posts I fixed.

Comment: Important point: the devs have a tool for this, which would save your effort, the user's effort, and the patience of everyone seeing the front screen. For similar actions, please flag me down. I just did several hundred, for example.

Comment: @MarcGravell: OK.

Answer (score 8):

We have an internal tool useful for bulk-deleting common phrases in a user's posts, and I have used this to clean up a few hundred more - however, it is possible I missed some patterns (it isn't the case that there is a single signature on all of your posts - many have never had any, etc). If there are a few more patterns you want removed, let me know which (example posts, please).

The advantage of this mechanism is that it **does not** bump the questions to the front page.

Comment: You can see the the pattern of my signatures in these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137821/problem-with-set-quoted-identifier(question), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421257/intercept-javascript-event/1421372#1421372 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476967/pros-and-cons-of-serverside-javascript-implementation

Comment: And there are more than 5000 posts with the signature starting with 'cheers', check the link http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cheers

Comment: @RameshVel it is gone from the markdown from most of them - it looks like it is staying around in the markup for some (not sure why), but I'm not going to go through refreshing them all - I think it's fine as is... just... stop adding them ;p

Comment: (found and fixed a pile more)_

Comment: thank you.   i stopped doing that long time ago.. Those were added before that..

Comment: @Ramesh funnily enough, one reason some got missed is that you have a combination of "Ramesh Vel", "RameshVel", "Rames Vel", "Rameh Vel", etc...