# Why do I see "Too many edits"?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, edits, rate-limiting

I am confused, as I thought we already fixed that problem in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171960/6309) (March 2013).

> this limit should now scale with reputation. Folks who are posting many answers every day for long periods of time might well need to make more edits to old ones, so the system should recognize this.

I asked:

> Will we have more specific details on this limit? Will it be the same on Stack Overflow and for all the other SE sites?

[Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) answered

> Same everywhere.

### And you should never ever hit it on SO.

Well.. I am in the process of editing all my answers including pictures not saved on i.stack.imgur.com (from [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/132951/find-my-questions-and-answers-with-imgur-in-the-body)): I have 102 answer to edit.

**And I don't want to think about an "edit limit"**

Is there any way I can avoid seeing this?

[image: Too many edits?]

As I said in my previous question:

> Seriously, how many high rep users (>50K, >100K) have been exhibiting bad edit behavior?
> **Let dedicated users do their work.**

Comment: Ah no, that's the new "stop improving your content" filter. It's to prevent users like you from making us regulars look bad.

Comment: It's probably a photosensitive epilepsy protection!

Comment: Freehand circles **and drop shadows!!!!!1**

Comment: One silly way around is open another browser in private/incognito mode, suggest edits to all your posts and approve quickly before others will reject it. There is no limit on suggested edits. Yeah, ironic!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I should write a userscript... :-)

Comment: Heh, Kevin's answer stated "Past a certain point, the limit will be removed altogether." too...seems kind of hard to imagine that you haven't hit that point yet.

Comment: maybe someone forgot to push an update... :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but can anons include images in their edits? I believed they can't :(

Comment: @Mołot good point... oh well, was worth a try. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The specific code path of the edit page didn't take account of the privilege change.

It is now fixed and will be with you in the next build.

Comment: I'm affected by this in [here](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1905/9096) as well (5 posts limit per 561 rep)?

Answer (score 16):

<del>It must have been a temporary glitch</del>:

I was editing "[“Add File to Blackberry Project” option is missing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059356/6309)" when it happened.

I ended up somehow on the url **https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2059356/edit**, which always display the "You have already edited 18 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts)." message.

But when I edited again that question, it worked, and I have now done 2 more edits to other answers.

There must be something in that url '`/posts/xxx/edit`' which still honor the old edit limit.

---

This is reproducible: if you access directly to the `posts/xxx/edit` url, you will see that error message. If you edit the "normal" way (inline edit), you won't see it.

Comment: @hims056: thank you for the edit: "inline edit" was what I meant indeed.

Comment: Nice detective work there - should make this easier to find and fix. Thanks!