# How many edits can a high-rep user have?

Tags: support, edits, rate-limiting

> 5 edits on own posts per day, more for high-rep users (scales with reputation)

[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900) does not say anything about the exact number a high-rep user can have. Can someone tell me how many edits can a high-rep user have(not just on his own posts)?

Comment: Looks like it's kept secret for a reason. Best description [can be found here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171952/152859).

Comment: As for other users posts, I think there is no limit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Editing other users posts is not limited. As a proof, just run [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426654/top-daily-edits).

Top daily editor at the moment is [hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre?tab=activity) with 2820 (!!!) edits on a single day, December 24<sup>th</sup> 2012. You can verify this by sifting through the [user's revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=310).

The system probably counts on the fact edits bump the questions to the front page so it's easy to detect abuse and in such case suspend the offending user.

As for editing own posts, which can be done even with 1 rep it's limited for a good reason and the exact algorithm of reputation scaling is kept secret for a reason, most likely to prevent abuse, even by high rep users. Best description can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171952/152859):

> Broadly speaking, the higher your reputation the more edits you'll be able to make before running into this anti-vandalization cutoff. Past a certain point, the limit will be removed altogether.

Comment: Surprised you didn't pick [this user](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173682/get-edits-per-day-for-specific-user?userid=367456). 2,846 edits on Xmas eve (Edit: Fixed link)

Comment: @MartinSmith I used [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173723/get-top-editors) as basis, how did you find this hakre guy? :)

Comment: [Just a minor tweak to your query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/173724/get-edits-per-day-for-specific-user)

Comment: Wtf... How is that even possible? I've looked at three consequent tag edits which were actually different (i.e. not removing the same tag), and they all were done in two seconds... (2/3 sec for an edit, ??)

Comment: @nicael good question. Might be using a script of some kind.