# Are self-edit limits only imposed on sub2k reputation accounts?

Tags: support, edits, rate-limiting

I have a superuser.com account that's sub 2000 reputation points.  I have an Arqade account with 20k+ reputation points.

I am unable to self-edit my own questions up to 5 times a day? according to this error message:

[image]

However, on my own questions on Arqade, I have never once seen this message, despite going over 100s of my own questions for self-edits.

I would just like to confirm that this is "Too many edits" page only shows for sub2k accounts. I have never seen this message before in my time here on SE.

Comment: I'm guessing it's to prevent newer users from using the edit as a "bump" for their question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any user, no matter their reputation, will have a limit on how many of their old posts (old being not created in the past 48 hours) they can edit in a single day - but it does scale depending on your reputation (starts at 5). This is a restriction similar to the limit on the number of your own posts you can *delete* in the same day - designed to prevent users from mass destruction of their own content if they're trying to rage-quit or their account has been hijacked, or from bumping or changing all of their questions to get answers.

Comment: How much does it scale exactly? I'd like to know since I picked today to go over my really old questions on superuser as I would on any other network site to clean up old questions and title them better.  What's the exact ratio? Is it something we can't know?

Comment: @Rusemaster yeah, probably a secret, at least [that's what I thought a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224726/152859). :)