# Random accepting of edits

Tags: discussion, support, review

At the moment, there are a ton of edits that just change `andriod` to `android` and they are getting approved.

- http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1375656
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1375663
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1375667
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1375668

and a crap load more. All are originating from the user [pixelpusher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238870/pixelpusher). Can we do something about this? Like require a certain number of something to be able to submit your edit?

Comment: I've grown to stop caring, because no, there's really not anything we can do. A lot of people will tell you "it's still improving the post." Apparently the "too minor" rejection reason is only a reason of convenience and not practice.

Comment: @animuson I generally don't care about having to reject them, but when it floods the system...

Comment: I've [left a small comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418415/adobe-air-nativealert-for-ios-and-android#comment20155603_12418415) for the user, pointing him to this discussion. I'm repeating myself on a daily basis, but the real issue is with the reviews, not the editor.

Comment: @Bart Thats what I'm getting at - the fact that people are supposed to reject those, but they just click through them to get rep...

Comment: @ColeJohnson The design of the system is that if the reviewers actually rejected the inappropriate edits then the submitter would be banned from suggesting edits if they had a lot of edits denied in a short space of time.

Comment: @Servy well, maybe they shouldn't flood the system

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm pretty sure there is a limit to the number of per-user pending suggested edits.  In any case, as I said, if they were rejected as they should be the system would be working just fine.  You need to focus on fixing the reviewers, not the suggestors.  That said, it's a problem we have not yet been able to solve (or even mitigate).

Comment: @Servy Are you getting at the 20 reviews per category per UTC day? I mentioned that

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, I am not referring to that at all.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164503/gaming-the-edit-system-with-tiny-edits. This is the same problem. Start rejecting!

Comment: Welcome to the wasteland that is the Suggested Edit queue

Comment: Well, it looks like he was a spam account I think. [His page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1238870/pixelpusher) was just advertising for a discount "doctor" site, but now says "delete me"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's also doing it from `Twiter` to `Twitter` in the title.

It's fine when that's the only thing wrong, but too often there are other things to be fixed including other of the same misspellings in the content.  Someone needs to let him know that he should be fixing all the problems in a post, not just the one misspelling.

Comment: And anyone can, with an @ comment on any of the posts where the edit was accepted. My preference is to fix everything else then leave an @ comment explaining how to see revisions to see those other fixes, and encourage them to fix **everything** when they find one thing wrong.