# What does it mean to ragequit?

Tags: discussion

I have seen some references to the term, "ragequit".  Being somewhat new to SO, I am intrigued.  What exactly does ragequitting entail?

Comment: Just google it. It's not specific to SO/SE.

Comment: It's when I downvote some of your posts on [so] and you get so angry that someone dared to vote down your gems, that you email team@se and request deletion of your account on [parenting.se] to teach them basterds a lesson :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Rage quitting is when a user gets extremely angry about something—probably trivial—then goes on a *rage* and makes malicious edits, deletes their useful content, etc.

And then *quits*.

It creates a lot of work for the moderators to un-do the damage, and as a result there are mechanisms in place to try to mitigate the damages: edits cause a question to bump up in the relevant active pages, you can't delete more than 5 of your posts in one day, etc.

Comment: a/ this "limitation" needs to disappear for high-rep users, as I request in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129634/reconcile-the-5-edits-limit-with-a-large-set-of-updates-of-ones-old-answers. b/ This limitation doesn't prevent malicious edits anyway (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171560/6309)

Comment: @VonC - I don't have a strong opinion on this either way, especially with the awesome workaround in your second link.  That said, I do believe there have been known instances of 10 and 20K+ users rage quitting, so I'm not sure blanket-trusting all users by rep would entirely eliminate this concern / problem.

Comment: blanket-trusting all users? How about 200K+ users ;-) ? And no, there are, for now, no known instance of rage-quiting for high-rep users: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129634/reconcile-the-5-edits-limit-with-a-large-set-of-updates-of-ones-old-answers/171560#comment504377_170433

Comment: @VonC - interesting.  Yeah, I think they could probably loosen up some of the rules with minimal risk.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that someone gets really angry during a game/argument/etc so they just rage at everyone and then leave.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of SO, I suppose it would mean that a user is enraged or angry at something about SO and decided to never ask/answer at SO again.

Needless to say, it's a bad idea.

Comment: In SO, it's often specific to users who delete or vandalize their own content before quitting.