# Giving edit reputation bonus for same user for same post multiple times

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, review, suggested-edits

On Stack Overflow, I saw some users editing the same question multiple times, and getting the 2 point reputation bonus for each time.

I saw it during review of a suggested edit (some months ago, I forgot the question that's why I'm unable to paste the link here). I rejected it and gave the reason in the "Other" reason field.

Most of the time I saw that users first formats the code, and then after approval they edit the title and fix the grammar.

Why is this allowed?

My point is, if an user gained 2 reputation points for a particular edit, then why give another 2 points again for the same post? Because the second edit on same question/answer means that there were some mistakes or misses in their previous edit.

Comment: There are cases like user A suggest edit to fix something; it gets approved then the OP is adding more code or whole section which also need fixing. User A edit again. Maybe feature like "if there was no edit between consecutive suggested edits on the same post, only the first give 2 reputation points when approved".

Comment: You can review [your Revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp?tab=activity&sort=reviews) if you actually wanted to locate the question.

Comment: Don't worry; I just noticed how many Revisions you have :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this should be changed so that rep gained from editing only applies if the edit was non-consecutive with that user's previous edits on that post.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to game the system like that, but consider the following case:

1. OP creates a question with some grammatical errors.
2. User A edits the question to fix the errors.
3. OP/User B edits the question to add code/stack traces.
4. User A edits the question to add code blocks / fix other errors.

User A deserves credit for both edits in this case, so we can't just blanket prevent them from getting additional credit for extra suggested edits on a question.

It's possible there could be a check that says "Are they suggesting an edit to a question where they last edited it (by suggestion)?" but that seems like a really specific use case (and would be up to the staff). I doubt it's worthwhile as the gaming user would get a very limited amount of rep this way.

Note that there is a [scaling edit limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171960/164454) based on reputation, so they'd also need some rep already to get any real impact from gaming the system like this.