# Should editing same post twice given twice reputation points?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, review

Today I came across a scenario,
Where I edited post came in review. After few minutes it was got accepted as edit and I got +2 reputations. But After reading the post i realized I missing few characters to change. So went back to edit page of post and edited the post with original post which user posted. And after few minutes I got +2 reputation again for same Post.
[image]

My question is should twice editing a same post given reputation twice?

I am not saying its a bug or its to be implemented. i just wanted to discuss.

Comment: Check[Giving edit reputation bonus for same user for same post multiple times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186068/giving-edit-reputation-bonus-for-same-user-for-same-post-multiple-times)

Comment: I agree with accepted answer there. If both consecutive edits got accepted, it means first one was too minor, really, and shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: I think both answers in the linked possible duplicate are right.  It can be gamed, but it can also be a valid edit.  I don't think we should do away with the 2nd +2 but the limit suggested by the suggested edit would help with the gaming.

Comment: It's a measly 2 rep. And it's a gamble - there is no guarantee the edit will be accepted. It isn't the hustle on the century, so IMVHO just accept it and move on.

Comment: @slugster to a new user +2 rep is huge. To a 10k user +2 rep is measly.

Comment: @danielhanly.com typically though, I don't think we want to discourage editing.  The max any 1 user can get from editing is 1000 rep (500 edits), so even if they game the system to get to 1000, they are still a long ways away from any privileges that can cause significant harm.  And if they do it enough, they will get caught, so I think changing it has only a limited benefit and probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @psubsee2003 ah, I did not know about the limits! I've now officially changed sides of the fence, please disregard my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should happen!

I wouldn't want a scenario where people are purposefully leaving out some punctuation/grammar amendments, just to gain an additional 2 rep after a 2nd edit.

The +2 should be a thank you for improving the post.
Once you've done that, you can edit further out of the goodness of your heart (because we're all good people, obviously), but not gain any reward for it.

Comment: I also don't want a scenario where people are purposefully leaving out some punctuation/grammar amendments, that is why I am asking a question "Should editing same post twice given twice reputation points?"