# Reputation points increment with every edit on the same post

Tags: bug, reputation, edits

I saw that if I edit a post once then it gives me a +2. But then if I again edit the same post then I get another +2. Isn't this wrong?

Reputation points must be awarded only once per question. The successive edits must be treated as the correction of the previous edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving edit reputation bonus for same user for same post multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186068/giving-edit-reputation-bonus-for-same-user-for-same-post-multiple-times) which is the dupe-target of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195740/398063

Comment: @OP the answer comes down to: if your edit is approved twice, that means you've added contributions, twice, that are good enough to merit changing the question. So, twice the reward!