# Stackoverflow 5 editable post a day

Tags: support, moderators, edits

I know there is a discussion for this:
[Reconcile the 5 edits limit with a large set of updates of one's old answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129634/reconcile-the-5-edits-limit-with-a-large-set-of-updates-of-ones-old-answers)

But is there a way to ask a moderator to fix another posts or are they also limited to a 5 post change per day? I need to do is fix 2 more posts today and I am good, I don't want to wait if I don't have to. I was just wondering if there is a way to contact a moderator i.e send them a message. (I may be missing something on the header and could be able to talk to a moderator right now, but I would like it to be pointed out if it is there)

Comment: Moderators do have limits on time.  We are not likely to do things for you that you can do yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering if there is a way to contact a moderator i.e send them a message.

To contact a moderator for such a thing, you can always use the "flag button" and explain your request in the "other" section.

> [image]

It will be handled as soon as a moderator takes care of your flag. I cannot guarantee your request will be accepted but it will be heard.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned the best way to ask for mod help is with a mod flag, but I doubt the flag would be handled today...

Moderators have a lot to handle on any given day, don't take up their time with something you could easily handle yourself by simply waiting till tomorrow.